# job sequence program example

Tags: java, collections

I am writing code for sorting job according to decreasing profit order. compiler gives error "int cannot be deferenced". whats wrong with comparator code?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Job {

    char jobId;
    int deadLine;
    int profit;

    public Job(char j, int d, int p) {
        jobId = j;
        deadLine = d;
        profit = p;
    }

    public int getProfit() {
        return profit;
    }
}

public class JobSequencingProblem {

    public void sequence(ArrayList<Job> list) {
        Comparator<Job> cmp = new Comparator<Job>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Job j1, Job j2) {
                int p1 = j1.profit;
                int p2 = j2.profit;
                return (j1.getProfit()).compareTo(j2.getProfit());
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JobSequencingProblem j = new JobSequencingProblem();
        ArrayList<Job> list = new ArrayList<Job>();
        list.add(new Job('a', 2, 100));
        list.add(new Job('b', 1, 19));
        list.add(new Job('c', 2, 27));
        list.add(new Job('d', 1, 25));
        list.add(new Job('e', 3, 15));
        j.sequence(list);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write `int.compareTo(int)`, that only works with `Integer` objects. But you can use [`Integer.compare(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#compare-int-int-) instead:

```
Comparator<Job> cmp = new Comparator<Job>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Job j1, Job j2) {
        int p1 = j1.profit;
        int p2 = j2.profit;
        return Integer.compare(j1.getProfit(), j2.getProfit());
    }
};
```

Note that you also don't need the two `int p1 = j1.profit` lines and your `sequence` method currently does nothing (as also pointed out in the comments).

When using Java 8 you can optimize your code to this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

class Job {

    char jobId;
    int deadLine;
    int profit;

    public Job(char j, int d, int p) {
        jobId = j;
        deadLine = d;
        profit = p;
    }

    public int getProfit() {
        return profit;
    }
}

public class JobSequencingProblem {

    public void sequence(List<Job> list) {
        list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Job::getProfit));
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JobSequencingProblem j = new JobSequencingProblem();
        List<Job> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Job('a', 2, 100));
        list.add(new Job('b', 1, 19));
        list.add(new Job('c', 2, 27));
        list.add(new Job('d', 1, 25));
        list.add(new Job('e', 3, 15));
        j.sequence(list);
    }
}
```

For further reading: [Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

Comment: In Java 8 you can also do `Comparator<Job> cmp = Comparator.comparingInt(job -> job.profit.getProfit());`. For the record, the `sequence()` method does absolutely nothing either way.

Comment: @shmosel There's too much `profit` in your comment (pun intended). But it can get even simpler ;)

Comment: You're right. I was confused by those useless variables in the original.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to sort a list, you have two solutions:

1. either you provide a Comparator (as you proposed)
2. or each element in your collection implements the Comparable interface

Example with Comparator (in Java8)

```
class Job {

    char jobId;
    int deadLine;
    int profit;

    public Job(char j, int d, int p) {
        jobId = j;
        deadLine = d;
        profit = p;
    }

    public int getProfit() {
        return profit;
    }   
}

public class JobSequencingProblem {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<Job> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Job('a', 2, 100));
        list.add(new Job('b', 1, 19));
        list.add(new Job('c', 2, 27));
        list.add(new Job('d', 1, 25));
        list.add(new Job('e', 3, 15));

        list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Job::getProfit));
    }
}
```

Example with Comparable

```
class Job implements Comparable<Job> {

    char jobId;
    int deadLine;
    int profit;

    public Job(char j, int d, int p) {
        jobId = j;
        deadLine = d;
        profit = p;
    }

    public int getProfit() {
        return profit;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Job o) {
        return Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::intValue).
            compare(this.getProfit(), o.getProfit());
    }
}

public class JobSequencingProblem {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        List<Job> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Job('a', 2, 100));
        list.add(new Job('b', 1, 19));
        list.add(new Job('c', 2, 27));
        list.add(new Job('d', 1, 25));
        list.add(new Job('e', 3, 15));

        list.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
    }
}
```

In this case, the "naturalOrder" will be deduced from Comparable implementation